# How do I import items of a list?

Tags: python

I'm still with my URL to DOC converter, but I have a problem.
I want to import x.
I say:

```
for x in range(1, 7):
    import imports[x]
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I want it to import item `x` of list `imports`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
import importlib

for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    importlib.import_module('foo.' + i)
```

If you want something more versatile, you can use `exec`

```
x = 'foo'
y = 'bar'
exec('from ' + x + ' import ' + y, locals(), globals())
```

Comment: Nope, tried         importlib.import_module(imports[x]). And gives error.

Comment: @Alex82 What mistakes? You are using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: oops, forgot to pip install!

Comment: I have not used Python 2. What is the error message? Have you tried using `exec`?

Comment: Invalid syntax, and says:  import imports[x]
                                                         ^

Comment: You tried to adapt my code I posted above to your project? I never did to use `import imports[x]`.

Comment: No, that was before. import imports[x] was my try, but it doesn't work.